# Can't import sbt project in intellij 14

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-14

After "import from existing sources" and poiting to a directory with an sbt file, I do not get the option to import according to the sbt model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the sbt file needs to be explicitly called `build.sbt`, though the import dialog does not state that.